# Blender 3D objects are shaking in viewport when it's too far from center

Tags: objects, 3d-view, coordinates

If you place any object in the viewport really far away from the center and start to rotate, it starts shaking/giggling...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem by not moving objects to center?

And here is a test blend scene: [image]

This kind of problem usually occurs when you need to import .dxf files that contain exact coordinates of lines and not allowed to move!

Comment: Please upload blend files to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ rather than elsewhere. Other locations can expire or become no longer available. Example videos are best converted to animated gif and added to the question as an image to make them more accessible to others reading the question, without having to open an external link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical 3d systems use internally floating point arithmetics in single precision (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). When floats get larger they (by design) get less precise. Hence you see these staggerings. Also other systems have these limitations.

I worked on a custom pipeline where everything was stored on disk relative to a specific point in the world. Per scene we had an offset that was applied during loading so that the center of attention was always near the origin. We did all this to overcome the limitations of floating point.

Systems that need to be more precise (like CAD systems) typically use double precision or do not use floating point arithmetics. But that will give you a performance penalty.